# Print out to file using Grep

Tags: python

I'm trying to check reverse lookup of IP address and then write the result to txt file. How I can write the result to file using grep ?

My script:

```
import sys, os, re, shlex, urllib, subprocess 

cmd = 'dig -x %s @192.1.1.1' % sys.argv[1]

proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()

sys.stdout = open("/tmp/test.txt", "w")
print(out)
sys.stdout.close()
```

Comment: `with open('/tmp/test.txt', 'w') as f: f.write(out)`

Comment: Where is the regex part of this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited after comment**
To only print out a line containing the string `'PTR'`, first split the output into a list of lines (each line being a `str`), then loop over the lines and check if they contain `'PTR'`:

```
import sys, os, re, shlex, urllib, subprocess 

cmd = 'dig -x %s @192.1.1.1' % sys.argv[1]

proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = proc.communicate()

# Convert to list of str lines
out = out.decode().split('\n')

# Only write the line containing "PTR"
with open("/tmp/test.txt", "w") as f:
    for line in out:
        if "PTR" in line:
            f.write(line)
```

Further explanation of the syntax: The `out` object returned from `proc.communicate()` is not a `str` but a `bytes` object. The `out.decode()` does the conversion from `bytes` to `str`. We then split the string up into lines using `.split('\n')`. We can now iterate over these lines using the for loop and ask whether `"PTR"` is a substring of any of the lines. If it is, write the corresponding line to the file. Note that if multiple lines contain `"PTR"`, they will all be written to the file, without a separating newline.

Comment: Yes, but this is more in line with the attempt in the question. Also, unlike `f.write(out)`, `print(out, file=f)` works regardless of the type of `out` (I think here, `out` is of type `bytes`)

Comment: Hi. Can't understand your answers -
Let's say I get a result with a lot of lines. But I want you to write to the file only a line containing the word "PTR".
How can I get it in my script?

Comment: I have updated the answer accordingly. Does the solution work for you?

Comment: Work for me. Can you explain the syntax ?